# Does Go block on processor intensive operations like Node?

Tags: node.js, go, concurrency

Go is great for concurrency, tasks are passed as go-routines, and go-routines are processed in a virtual processor, whenever one go-routine experience a blocking operation (a database call), the go-routine is moved to another virtual processor on a different thread, which is most of the time run on another physical processor ... now, we achieve parallelism.

Node.js has a similar technique (except everything happens on the same thread), but putting all waiting virtual processes in a waiting queue, till they receive responses from the blocking resource (DB, URL), then they are send to be processed.

The down side of Node.js, is its inability to handle processor intensive operations (for loop is an example), and the virtual process being in action, will take all the time till finish without preemption, that's why Node.js is regarded wisely before it's used in critical systems, despite it's high concurrency availability.

Yes, Go spawns a new thread to handle the blocking go-routine, but how about the processor intensive operations, are they regarded the same, or suffer from Node problems?

Comment: The go runtime doesn't use so many threads / processes  as you think.

Comment: @TheHippo, the run time has 10,000 threads limit, and you can increase them

Comment: @hobbs, properly written code or not is not the issue now, Erlang, for example, has something called reductions, which limits the number of cpu cycles per virtual process. and at the same time, still cooperative multi-tasking

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, but it's much more difficult to run into in practice than with Node, and much easier to recover from. Node is single-threaded unless you write explicitly multiprocess code (which isn't always easy, especially if you want to be portable). Go uses N:M scheduling with a certain maximum number of running threads (equal to the number of logical CPUs by default, but tunable). Note *running*: a goroutine that is waiting for a blocking operation is "frozen" and doesn't count as occupying a running thread.

So, if you have a single goroutine doing something CPU-intensive, it generally won't have an impact on other goroutines' ability to run, because there are a bunch of other threads available to run them. If *all* of your goroutines are occupied with computation, then it's true that other ones won't get a chance to run until one gives up the CPU. This might not *necessarily* be a problem if they're actually getting work done, since all of your CPUs are doing actual work, but of course sometimes it can be in latency-sensitive situations.

If it is a problem, three solutions come to mind:

1. Use `runtime.Gosched` during long computations to yield control of the processor, allowing other goroutines a chance to run. No other change has to be made; it's just a way of working with the cooperative scheduler. `Gosched` might return immediately, or it might return later.
2. Use a worker pool to limit the amount of parallel CPU-intensive work to less than GOMAXPROCS. Go makes this pretty easy.
3. Flipside of the same coin: raise GOMAXPROCS above the expected number of parallel compute tasks. This is probably the worst of the ideas, and will hurt scheduling at least somewhat, but it will still work, and ensure you have threads available for handling events.

Comment: Perfectly answered! I have a couple of questions for you: 1- What do you mean by: "Note running: a goroutine that is waiting for a blocking operation is "frozen" and doesn't count as occupying a running thread"?
.... 2- You say that I should use `runtime.Gosche` during long computations, does this mean I can/should manually interrupt my long-running/comutationally-expensive process in order to yield the processor control?

Comment: just to make sure I understand what you say: Go usually start with one thread, and when one of the go-routines make processor intensive operation, Go automatically create more threads, and handle the rest of go-routeins, is that right?

Comment: 1) Yes, you can/should use `runtime.Gosched` to yield the CPU periodically if you're going to do long compute tasks. 2) No, go *always* schedules goroutines on `runtime.GOMAXPROCS` threads (which defaults to the number of CPUs). No magical detecting. A goroutine that's blocked on a system call or a channel read doesn't occupy one of those threads.

Comment: There still some ambiguity in my understanding to some point: Does go treat blocking I/O the same way it treats processor intensive operations - they are all blocking - or they are treated differently as Node does?

Comment: @securecurve differently. A goroutine that performs a blocking syscall is blocked, but the thread it was running on is freed up to run another goroutine, so the program can keep moving.

Comment: I recently read that the NodeJS engine follow the same strategy as well, moving the serving thread, by moving the blocking operation to a newly created thread

Answer (score 1):

Go uses [cooperative multitasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking). A goroutine that doesn't do anything that cedes control to the Go scheduler, can monopolize a thread.

Comment: From the same link: `As a cooperatively multitasked system relies on each process regularly giving up time to other processes on the system, one poorly designed program can consume all of the CPU time for itself`

Comment: This means it suffers from the same Node.js problems regarding processor intensive operations

Comment: @securecurve Yes. But if you want you can block a thread/process in almost every language.

Comment: @TheHippo, I don't agree, Erlang is not the same. It has something called reductions, which counts the number of cpu cycles per virtual process, then, that process is forcefully preempted, when it hits the reductions count