# How can I check if reading from a tcp socket will block?

Tags: sockets, go, tcp

If I have a tcp connection `conn`, how can determine whether `conn.Read` will block?

My understanding is that Go's Read uses non-blocking sockets and will only block if there's no data available to read (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36117724/4447365).

But is there any way to check if the socket has no data available?

This can be done with the POSIX [read function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) by calling it with a `count` argument of zero.

Comment: The fact that you want to check implies you may have a design flaw, and this is likely an XY Problem. Can you detail what you're trying to accomplish that you think you need to perform such a check?

Comment: Not knowing anything about the context of what you're working on is exactly the problem, and is why I asked for additional details on what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: @rnickb: When writing in Go you aren't using POSIX. It'll work the same in Windows (mostly). When using Go, write Go.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11552492/13422

Comment: Ummm... 'you may have a design flaw' - not you do have a design flaw'.  Note that you comment flirts with violating the SO CoC.

Answer (score 0):

When programming in Go don't worry about it. Assume everything will block. Then put it in a goroutine so it runs asynchronously anyway.

The Go runtime handles all of the details.

Also, [the issue here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10940) seems to be what you want to do. The issue was rejected: Go doesn't do that. Neither does C. And even if it did it isn't reliable. If you read down to the end there are suggested solutions involving the Linger TCP setting.